# How to get element from json response in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

In python i am getting response like :

```
{'destination_addresses': ['402, I Park, Plot No. 15], 'origin_addresses': [Sector 19, Haryana 122008, India'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '1.7 km', 'value': 1672}, 'duration': {'text': '6 mins', 'value': 342}, 'duration_in_traffic': {'text': '6 mins', 'value': 334}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}
```

I want to get value inside distance how can i get this value can anyone please help me related this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary = {
  'destination_addresses': [
    '402, I Park, Plot No. 15], 'origin_addresses': [Sector 19, Haryana 122008, India'
  ],
  'rows': [
    {
      'elements': [
        {
          'distance': {
            'text': '1.7 km',
            'value': 1672
          },
          'duration': {
            'text': '6 mins',
            'value': 342
          },
          'duration_in_traffic': {
            'text': '6 mins',
            'value': 334
          },
          'status': 'OK'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  'status': 'OK'
}

print(dictionary['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance'])
```

Comment: Thanx it is useful for me

Answer (score 1):

You have nested array structure so, let's assume you're using `request` then:

```
json = response.json()

for r in json['rows']:
    for e in r['elements']:
        print(e['distance'])
```

Comment: correct but i dont want to use anyways thanks to you so much